# Creating and running docker containers cluster with Kubernetes on AWS

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes

I downloaded kubernetes (using the command below):

```
export KUBERNETES_PROVIDER=aws; wget -q -O - https://get.k8s.io | bash
```

Now I have 4 minions machine and one master machine in my aws account.

I want my cluster to run 3 docker containers (just a random number), just to see how this works.

currently I don't have my own docker containers so I want to create just demo ones, maybe using some popular image from the docker hub.(image to create containers of https://hub.docker.com/r/williamyeh/scala/)

How do I proceed from here? How do I create those containers and link them with the cluster?

I'm using Mac.

Comment: This does not seem a question for Stackoverflow as it has little to do with programming. You might want to try one of the other stack sites such as serverfault or superuser to have a better chance of relevant answers. Be sure to check the site help to see where the question is the most on-topic.

Comment: Like Gimby said this isn't a question for Stackoverflow. When you want to use docker with kubernetes I would recommend exploring OpenShift 3.1

Comment: @Gimby I posted in serverfault earlier, but still didnt get answer. Im tring to find the right info on the web but cannot find the scenario I need...:/

Comment: @ninja well kubernetes is cutting edge technology, and the way you ask the question pretty much calls for a lengthy how-to guide which takes time and patience to write up. It doesn't surprise me that it will take time before this gets answered, if at all.

Comment: @Gimby ok I get it. I know it might now get answered, but as an advanced programmer, could you direct me to a place where I can learn those steps online?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to familiarize yourself with some basic kubernetes concepts such as [pods](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/pods/) and [services](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/). You can also follow [step-by-step examples](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.2/examples/README.md) to learn how to run real applications.